# sqlalchemy/postgresql: get database 'as-of' timestamp of a query

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy and Postgresql and I am doing an complex query (that may result in no rows) and I need the 'as-of timestamp' of the results I am getting from the server (i.e the current timestamp of when this query was executed by the database).

How could I achieve this?

Comment: you can add a `now() as_of` column to whatever select query you want to run. that extra column will hold the `timestamp`. you could run two queries 1 after the other, first to fetch the database timestamp & then the actual query. you could use the client's system time instead of the database time if that is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform your query within a transaction, then `localtimestamp` will refer to the transaction start time.

For example:

```
with engine.begin() as t:
    print(t.execute("SELECT localtimestamp").fetchone()[0])
    time.sleep(2)  
    print(t.execute("SELECT localtimestamp").fetchone()[0])
```

Which prints:

```
2017-10-19 09:52:44.646723
2017-10-19 09:52:44.646723
```

i.e. localtimestamp remains unchanged over the duration of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by running the following query:

```
select query_start
from pg_stat_activity
where query = 'YOUR_QUERY_HERE'
```

This gives you the time when the query started its execution in database in PostgreSQL. You could also find the start time of your query with other identifier like the query's `pid`, etc.

Of course, there is a lot more data about a query you can fetch from PostgreSQL using the `pg_stat_activity` table. You can find out more by visiting [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) link.